# Clone the "proceed to cart" button and place it above checkout on the cart page, but only appear display size is 320px

Tags: php, css, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I have cloned the "proceed to cart" button and float on the upper-right corner on the Woocommerce cart page. However I want this button to appear only when the browser is compressed (simulating mobile display), but go away when browser is stretched to the size of PC display. How to do it?

Here is the code I came up, but its not working.

```
if(width <= 320){    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'move_proceed_button' );
function move_proceed_button( $checkout ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() ) . '" 
class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" >' . __( 'Proceed to 
Checkout', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
    }
} else
if(width > 325){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'move_proceed_button' );
});
?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, qestions *specific* for this e-commerce plugin are off-topic. They have their own forum at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution to the above issue.
At your wordpress functions.php inside your child-theme folder, add this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'move_proceed_button' );
function move_proceed_button( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div class="mobile-checkout-btn text-right"><a href="' . esc_url( WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() ) . '" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" >' . __( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a></div>';
}
```

The above code will clone the "Proceed to Checkout" button and place it above checkout. Now to make it appear only when screen size is that of a mobile device. Add this css codes on your style.css inside your child-theme folder.

```
.mobile-checkout-btn {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
    .mobile-checkout-btn {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just call woocommerce proceed-to-checkout-button template in woocommerce_before_cart action hook as follows-

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'add_wc_button_proceed_to_checkout');
function add_wc_button_proceed_to_checkout(){
    echo '<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">';
    wc_get_template( 'cart/proceed-to-checkout-button.php' );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but the button will not disappear when I stretched the browser to the size of laptop display. It should go away when stretched, and will re-appear when I compress the browser like simulating for mobile display.

Comment: The button proceed_to_checkout is already responsive by woocommerce. But if you want to disappear the button for certain device sizes, then you have to write some custom css in @media.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate it. I did try this on style-responsive.css but did not work. Am I doing it right?


    @media(max-width: 480px) {
        .wc-proceed-to-checkout {
      text-align: center !important;
      display : block;
     }
    }
    @media(min-width: 500px) {
     .wc-proceed-to-checkout {
      text-align: center !important;
      display : none;
     }
     }

Comment: <code>@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {.wc-proceed-to-checkout { text-align: center !important; display : block; } } @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {.wc-proceed-to-checkout { text-align: center !important; display : none; } }</code>